# Ejecutar Bot para Telegram con Python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Estoy realizando un bot de Telegram, el caso es que ya he conseguido que funcione de manera sencilla al hablar con él por Telegram, pero sólo cuando lo estoy ejecutando en mi ordenador a través de la consola. El caso es que quiero que funcione siempre sin necesidad que mi ordenador esté funcionando, cómo debería proceder? He leído que con servicios de cloud computing como AWS se puede, pero no sé qué servicios debo tener.

Comment: Preguntas basadas en opiniones, terminan cerradas.

Comment: No es una opinión, es un problema y busco posibles soluciones.

Comment: Te recomiendo la lectura de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que te informes de la manera adecuada de formular una pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: ok, procederé a reformular, gracias